# Python : How to stop execution after exception has been caught?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have a class dataset.py that has a bunch of functions and also a logger implemented which looks like:

```
class dataset:
    def get_data():
        try:
            if(sourcefile != None):
                if not os.path.isfile(sourceFile):
                    raise FileNotFoundError
        except FileNotFoundError:
            logger.error('File not found!')
    def do_something():
        return
```

I use these classes in the following way:

```
datasetObj = dataset()
datasetObj.get_data()
datasetObj.do_something()
```

Now, even if get_data() raises a FileNotFoundError it is handled in the except block and the program continues to go to do_something().

How do I stop this? If there is a file not found error then execution should stop.
How do I return my exception to the caller and make my main.py from executing any further?

Comment: Why are you catching the exception?

Comment: because I want the logger to log it in the file. And if I dont catch it, i have no way of logging it.

Comment: You could just re `raise FileNotFoundError` after you log the error.

Comment: Either *not* catch the exception (let the code *using* `dataset()`) handle it instead), or set a flag on the instance and alter behaviour later on when `do_somehing()` is called.

Comment: @RoshanJoeVincent: you can always re-raise exceptions.

Comment: I thought about that, but is that the correct way of doing it? re-raising exceptions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay Ill try setting a flag and doing it. Thanks

Comment: @RoshanJoeVincent yes that's a standard way to log errors, if you still want your program to exit. Catch it, log it, re-raise it (or raise some other custom error).

Comment: @killian95 Okay Sure thanks a lot

Comment: @killian95 puting `raise <newException>` will kill the old stack trace and only point to your code. A bare `raise` will preserve it.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Good to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a couple things.

```
import sys # top of your code
sys.exit(1)
```

I believe you can also immediately raise the exception with:

```
raise
```

Do this right after your log in the except

Comment: `raise` would be the proper way to do something then send the exception up. This is doubly true if your code is called from another: let it have a chance to handle the exception.